# Getting Records Based Off Of Two Different ID's

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, recordset

I have been able to get records from the SQLite database when I have only one ID to search for.  For example I have passed my League Id to the Bowler Table and I am list all the bowlers associated to this Id.  Now when I create a Series for this bowler I am passing the League Id and the Bowler Id to the Series table to ensure that I am only getting the Series that belong to that bowler in a certain League.

To list the bowlers I used the following code;

```
public Bowler getBowler(String leagueId) {
        //Get Readable Database If We Are Not Inserting Anything
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Bowler.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Bowler.COLUMN_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(leagueId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Prepare Bowler Object
        Bowler bowler = new Bowler(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

        //Close Database Connection
        cursor.close();

        return bowler;
    }
```

To list the Bowlers Series I tried the following;

```
public Series getSeries(String leagueId, String bowlerId) {
        //Get Readable Database If We Are Not Inserting Anything
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query( Series.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Series.COLUMN_ID, Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Series.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID, Series.COLUMN_NAME, Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE, Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + Series.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(leagueId)}, null, null, null, null)
                new String[]{String.valueOf(bowlerId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Prepare Bowler Object
        Series series = new Series(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

        //Close Database Connection
        cursor.close();

        return series;
    }
```

I know this is incorrect and I don't know how to actually get this formatted correctly.

I am not sure if this is even the correct approach or if there is another way to accomplish the same thing, that could be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your selection query is incorrect. You are trying to select from two separate columns.

You have:
"WHERE series_idbowler_id =?"

what it looks like you want is"
"WHERE series_id =? AND bowler_id =?"

try formatting your query like this:

```
db.query( Series.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Series.COLUMN_ID, Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Series.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID, Series.COLUMN_NAME, Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE, Series.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
            Series.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?" + " AND " +  Series.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(leagueId), String.valueOf(bowlerId)}, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thus seemed to fix the issue. AT least the errors have been resolved.  I have other errors to work out before I can actually test it.